# Configuring eulexistdb with python bringing errors in django setting module

Tags: python, xml, exist-db

I have following code written in python in order to communicate with ExistDB using eulexistdb module.

```
from eulexistdb import db    
class TryExist:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = db.ExistDB(server_url="http://localhost:8899/exist")    
    def get_data(self, query):
        result = list()
        qresult = self.db.executeQuery(query)
        hits = self.db.getHits(qresult)
        for i in range(hits):
            result.append(str(self.db.retrieve(qresult, i)))
        return result

query = '''
let $x:= doc("/db/sample/books.xml")
return $x/bookstore/book/author/text()
'''
a = TryExist()
response = a.get_data(query)
print response
```

I am amazed that this code runs fine in Aptana Studio 3 giving me the output I want, but when running from other IDE or using command "python.exe myfile.py" brings following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EXISTDB_TIMEOUT, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I used my own localsetting.py to solve the problem using following code:

```
import os
# must be set before importing anything from django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'localsettings'
... writing link for existdb here...
```

Then I get error as:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

How do I configure the setting in Django to suit for ExistDB? Help me here please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind. I found the answer with little research from this [site](https://eulexistdb.readthedocs.org/en/0.17/existdb.html). What I did was created a **localsetting.py** file with following configurations.

```
EXISTDB_SERVER_USER = 'user'
EXISTDB_SERVER_PASSWORD = 'admin'
EXISTDB_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8899/exist"
EXISTDB_ROOT_COLLECTION = "/db"
```

and in my main file **myfile.py** I used :

```
from localsettings import EXISTDB_SERVER_URL
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'localsettings.py'
```

and In the class TryExist I changed in __ init __() as:

```
def __init__(self):
        self.db = db.ExistDB(server_url=EXISTDB_SERVER_URL)
```

PS: Using only **os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'localsettings'** brings the **django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.**.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code works in an IDE but not at the command line is probably that you have a difference in what Python environments are used to run your code.

I've done a couple of tests:

1. Virtualenv with `eulexistdb` installed but *not* Django. `eulexistdb` tries to load `django.conf` but fails and so does not try to get its configuration from a Django configuration. Ultimately, your code runs without error.
2. Virtualenv with 'eulexistdb`*and* Django:`eulexistdb`tries to load`django.conf` and succeed. I then tries to get is configuration from the Django configuration but fails. I get the same error you describe in your question.

To prevent the error in the presence of a Django installation, the problem can be fixed by adding a Django configuration like you did in your [accepted self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18265345/1906307). But if the code you are writing does not otherwise use Django, that's a bit of a roundabout way to get your code to run. The most direct way to fix the problem is to simply add a `timeout` parameter to the code that creates the `ExistDB` instance:

```
    self.db = db.ExistDB(
        server_url="http://localhost:8080/exist", timeout=None)
```

If you do this, then there won't be any error. Setting the `timeout` to `None` leaves the default behavior in place but prevents `eulexistdb` from looking for a Django configuration.